# fd_domain, equation doesn't work

Tags: prolog, clpfd

```
fd_domain([A, B, C], 0, 9), (A**(B+C)) #= ((A**B)*(A**C)).
```

Maybe some solutions? Seems ok ;P
I am getting that specific error:

```
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(#=)/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The power function seems to have limitations. In the GNU Prolog doc wie find:

9.6.1  FD arithmetic expressions
http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc329

That there is an error condition listed:

Errors
a sub-expression is of the form _ ** E and E is a variable      instantiation_error

Bye

Answer (score 1):

In YAP or SWI, you can use [`library(clpfd)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) which also permits integer exponentiation.  Propagation is not very strong, however.

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
?- [A,B,C] ins 0..9, A^(B+C) #= A^B*A^C.
   A in 0..9, A^C#=_A, A^B#=_B, A^_C#=_D,
   C in 0..9, B+C#=_C, B in 0..9, _B*_A#=_D, _C in 0..18
?- abs(X) #=< 7^7^7.
   X in -37598235267....
```

Please note that intervals are not restricted to machine word sizes like 2^32 or 2^64.